# Watch file for specific text and exit

Tags: grep, macos, tail

I'm trying to write a command that exits cleanly when a specific string is eventually written to a log file.

I've tried the following but it never exits.

*Setup: create a file for the purposes of testing the command.*

```
echo "Build completed." > build.log
```

*What I tried: these do not work, the commands never exit.*

```
tail -fn+0 build.log | grep -qe "completed"
```

```
tail -fn+0 build.log | grep --line-buffered -qe "completed"
```

*This works but is complex which leads me to believe I haven't found the idiomatic solution*

```
while true; do awk '/completed/{f=1; exit} END{exit !f}' && break; sleep 1; done < build.log
```

macOS Ventura 13.0, zsh

- https://ss64.com/osx/tail.html
- https://ss64.com/osx/grep.html

Comment: Have you tried piping `tail -f` to the awk command you have without using the shell loop?

Comment: Maybe you should use `tail -fn+0 build.log | grep -m 1 "completed"`.

Comment: @muru thanks for replying, I just tried `tail -fn+0 build.log | awk '/completed/{f=1; exit} END{exit !f}'` - it didn't work.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon thank you, I just tried `tail -fn+0 build.log | grep -m 1 "completed"`, it never exits.